# Floor values in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, floor

Hello I would like to establish a min value (0.3) in my `dat` dataframe:

```
col1   col2  col3  col4 
 0     0.2    0.8    1
 0.2    0     0.7   2.1
13.2   12.1   1.58   0
```

My expected output:

```
 col1   col2  col3  col4 
 0.3     0.3   0.8    1
 0.3     0.3   0.7   2.1
 13.2   12.1  1.58   0.3
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to do this

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) ifelse(x<0.3, 0.3, x))

> dat
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1  0.3  0.3 0.80  1.0
2  0.3  0.3 0.70  2.1
3 13.2 12.1 1.58  0.3
```

By using `dat[]` instead of only `dat` you can keep the class and structure of the existing data.frame. Otherwise, `dat` would be a list, since `lapply` returns a list.

In case you *do* have other columns that contain `factors` or `character` entries, you can still use `lapply` and specify which columns you want to be changed. If you had the following data.frame:

```
> dat
  col1 col2 col3 col4 id
1  0.0  0.2 0.80  1.0  a
2  0.2  0.0 0.70  2.1  b
3 13.2 12.1 1.58  0.0  c
```

You can use `lapply` as follows:

```
> dat[1:4] <- lapply(dat[1:4], function(x) ifelse(x<0.3, 0.3, x)) #only columns 1:4 will be changed

> dat                           #the id column is as it was and you still have a data.frame
  col1 col2 col3 col4 id
1  0.3  0.3 0.80  1.0  a
2  0.3  0.3 0.70  2.1  b
3 13.2 12.1 1.58  0.3  c
```

Answer (score 3):

Good-ol' vectorization at it's finest here.  Since we don't have any `factor` or `character` columns, we can treat `dat` as a `matrix` and replace the values directly.

```
## dat <- read.table(h=T, text = 'col1   col2  col3  col4 
##  0     0.2    0.8    1
##  0.2    0     0.7   2.1
##  13.2   12.1   1.58   0')

> min <- 0.3
> dat[dat < min] <- min
> dat
##   col1 col2 col3 col4
## 1  0.3  0.3 0.80  1.0
## 2  0.3  0.3 0.70  2.1
## 3 13.2 12.1 1.58  0.3
```

Comment: or `dat[] <- pmax(dat,min)`

Comment: Or `structure(data.frame(pmax(dat, min)))`.  But are you getting `NA` values that way?  I am.